# How to fetch data from MongoDB and data on Angular Module using Express Server

Tags: mongodb, express, angular2-routing

I created an application using Angular2 and Express server, also created a DataBase in MongoDB. my application using Angular Routing to navigate among pages. One of the page (products - for example) need to fetch and display data from MongoDB. 
The application bootstrapped from Express routing (index.html).

My query -

1. If I am using express routing then, how to load the Angular Module for product page. Is it possible to load the module from express routing?
2. How to pass data to product page, fetched from the MongoDB

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It seeems that you have two clearly separated questions here. The one about express and routing and the one about passing data from your db to the app. This discouraged here, please chose one, and create another question for the other.

Comment: Please let me rephrase my second question...
2. How to pass data to product page, fetched from from MongoDB using same express routing.

Comment: You can edit your question (and the title)